# Python 3, запись данных из цикла в переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть скрипт парсера на python 3.8 который я использую для парсинга значения слов на английском языке, который по итогу своей работы должен записать данные в файл. Чтобы получить определённые фрагменты текста в нужном виде я использую цикл.

```
phrase_ex_en = soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'en_p'})
for element in phrase_ex_en:
    print(element.get_text())
```

Для записи данных в файл, использую код

```
all_variable = [t1, t2, t3, t6, t7, t4, t5]

with open(str(name_url) + ".txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in all_variable:
        f.write(i)
```

Собственное вопрос, как результат работы цикла, все данные которые он выводит через print записать в одну переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поместить в список

```
mas = []
phrase_ex_en = soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'en_p'})
for element in phrase_ex_en:
    mas.append(element.get_text())
```

Это при условии, если код, который вы выложили работает так, как вы описали. Лучше добавлять в вопрос пример данных, с которыми вы работаете.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Ваш код помог решить мою задачу. Поменял тип переменной с list на str, почистил с помощью .replace и получил нужное мне форматирование текста.